# How to use Java 8 Date classes and Jackson with Spark?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, jackson

I have a Spark 1.4.0 project where I'm trying to parse several JSON records containing a timestamp field and store it in a [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object, using Jackson and the [JSR-310 module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310). If I try to run the driver program from the IDE (namely, IntelliJ IDEA 14.0) it runs correctly, but if I use [sbt assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) and `spark-submit`, then I get the following exception:

```
15/07/16 14:13:03 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3)
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mycompany.input.EventParser$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.com$fasterxml$jackson$module$scala$experimental$ScalaObjectMapper$_setter_$com$fasterxml$jackson$module$scala$experimental$ScalaObjectMapper$$typeCache_$eq(Lorg/spark-project/guava/cache/LoadingCache;)V
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper$class.$init$(ScalaObjectMapper.scala:50)
    at com.mycompany.input.EventParser$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.<init>(EventParser.scala:27)
    at com.mycompany.input.EventParser$$anonfun$1.apply(EventParser.scala:27)
    at com.mycompany.input.EventParser$$anonfun$1.apply(EventParser.scala:24)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:686)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:686)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have tried several versions of assembly, jackson and spark, but no luck. I guess this is somehow related to a dependency conflict between spark and my project (somehow, with the Guava library). Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT: example project to reproduce the issue [here](https://github.com/ale64bit/spark-jsr310).**

Comment: Check the versions of any jars in spark's own lib directory (e.g. jackson). Then ensure that you build against those exact same versions.

Comment: @Imm Seems like that Spark 1.4.0 uses Jackson 2.4.4, which is the same version I'm using in my project. Still, no luck. The same problem remains.

Comment: You are using the same versions of scala, right?

Comment: @Imm Yes, I tried with the same version of Scala (2.10.4). Also I compiled Spark myself with Scala 2.11, I also made an equivalent Maven project to try to shade the offending libraries. But still, no luck :(

Comment: I can post a minimal example project for reproducing the issue, if it helps.

Comment: All I can suggest is: find out which library com.mycompany.input.EventParser is in and which library com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper are in. Then look at mvn dependency:tree and check very carefully that the versions of neither have been changed, that everything that uses scala uses the same version of scala (and likewise java), and that the versions of libraries in the maven dependencies match those installed in the spark library directory that the cluster where you're running this uses. Your example will probably work fine on other people's clusters.

Comment: Not sure if this helps. but Jackson Scala module does rely on Guava so it has its own idea of which Guava to bring in. I think you should explicitly specify Guava version to use, although to figure out proper version may take time. You could start by using highest of differing versions that components require.

Comment: @StaxMan I tried to bring Guava 15.0 and 14.0.1 as well, but none of them makes any difference. The error persists. Any other idea? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Unfortunately all that is clear is that some part of the system is having trouble with Guava version different than what it was compiled to use. My other suggestion would be to try to upgrade to Jackson 2.5 (see the answer); that would eliminate one of Guava dependencies, as 2.5 of Scala module does NOT depend on Guava any more.

Comment: @kaktusito - Are you able to solve this? I am having the save issue. I am using `libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.3.5"`

Comment: @SamuelAlexander no luck yet. If you happen to find out the answer, please add it to this post.

Comment: @kaktusito - There was an issue with the JSON I've been using. After correcting that it worked.

Comment: @SamuelAlexander Have you solve this issuse?

Comment: @AllenXudongCheng - I just solved by using 2.3.5 version of jackson-module

Comment: Any update on this issue? I'm also having the same issue. Tried to work with version 2.3.5 and didn't solve it for me. Also tried to work with newest version 2.6.1 and didn't work.
Someone has any updates? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue and solved it by changing 2 things:

1) I used `ObjectMapper` instead of `ScalaObjectMapper` as suggested in a comment to this SO question: [Error in running job on Spark 1.4.0 with Jackson module with ScalaObjectMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334517/error-in-running-job-on-spark-1-4-0-with-jackson-module-with-scalaobjectmapper)

2) I needed to define the mapper inside the map operation.

```
val alertsData = sc.textFile(rawlines).map(alertStr => {
      val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
      mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
      mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
      broadcastVar.value.readValue(alertStr, classOf[Alert])
    })
```

If the mapper is defined outside I got a NullPointerException. Also tried to broadcast it and it didn't work.

Also, there is no need to explicitly add jackson as a dependancy as spark provides it.

Hope this helps.

Aliza

Comment: Similar to the `Learning Spark` example, but don't use the ScalaObjectMapper https://github.com/databricks/learning-spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/oreilly/learningsparkexamples/scala/BasicParseJsonWithJackson.scala

Comment: @Aliza But this wouldn't create an `ObjectMapper` per each element of the RDD? That sounds like an overkill. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @kaktusito You are right. See the solution I came up with here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495891/spark-broadcasting-jackson-objectmapper/32500040#32500040

Comment: @Aliza Thanks for the solution. I figured it out before seeing this. I was translating a Scalding program to Spark and encountered this problem.  It seems Spark doesn't serialize and distribute the whole class as Scalding does for Job class. It still feels weird to manually broadcast a JSON mapper.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that could help would be to upgrade to Jackson 2.5. While Jackson Scala module did depend on Guava up to version 2.4, this dependency was removed from 2.5 (there is `test` dependency for tests, but nothing for runtime).
This would at least eliminate transitive dependency conflict.

Comment: I also tried this, as suggested by you, but also didn't help. I uploaded a very simple project to reproduce the issue in github. See the edit in my question. Thanks for the help.